# Hypothesis testing books with problem sets and answers

Tags: hypothesis-testing, references

I want to find hypothesis testing books with **problem sets** and answers covering the topics:

- Testing variance
- Type 1 and type 2 errors
- Test parameters for Poisson and binomial
- Chi-squared test

I want to be able to read the question and determine on my own which test to be used.